# Is it possible to yank the entire element without moving to the beginning?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

When my cursor in middle of a word, and I want to yank the whole word, I must press <kbd>b</kbd> first, and press <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to yank it.

I want to know can I yank the word without hitting <kbd>b</kbd> first?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is yank around word, meaning if there is a space after the word, it will grab it too (but not a space before).

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is yank inside word, which yanks just the word characters.

You can see what will be yanked by <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to select the same characters. You could then also hit <kbd>y</kbd> to perform the yank.

`i` and `a` of course apply to all the other VIM groups, like `W`, which is any non whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

You can use <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. As a side effect, this will move the cursor to the beginning of the yanked area.

For more information, see [Text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) in the Vim documentation.

Comment: Actually, `byw` and `yaw` have pretty much the same effect.  Both move the cursor to the beginning of the yanked word, both require the same number of keystrokes.

Comment: That's true. But it answers the question in that you don't have to hit `b` first. :)

Comment: Oh, that's true!  Comparing with this criteria, `yaw` definitely leaves `byw` behind.  :-)